# Unable to implement pagination in DynamoDB DocumentClient

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using a React/DynamoDB stack for a project. I'm trying to get pagination to work using the `scan` method in DynamoDB DocumentClient. Here's the function I'm using:

```
async function getItems(lastItem?) {
  try {
    const params = {
      TableName: "posts",
      Limit: 1,
    };
    if (lastItem) {
      params.ExclusiveStartKey = { item_id: lastItem };
    }
    const response = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
    console.log(response)
    return {
      items: response.Items,
      lastItem: response.LastEvaluatedKey,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I use this component to `console.log` this response:

```
import { getItems } from "../../atoms/functions/AWS";

function Test() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => getItems()}>get item</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, with each click I'm getting the same result:

```
Object { Items: (1) […], Count: 1, ScannedCount: 1, LastEvaluatedKey: {…}, … }
"$response": Object { retryCount: 0, redirectCount: 0, maxRetries: 10, … }
​Count: 1
​Items: Array [ {…} ]
​LastEvaluatedKey: Object { postId: "2" }
ScannedCount: 1
```

I'm using a mock DynamoDB table with 5 posts - `postId: "1"`, `postId: "2"`, and so on.

Am I implementing the `getItems` function incorrectly? How can I modify the above code to paginate through all the posts?

**EDIT:**

I updated my component in line with Mark B's suggestion:

```
function Test() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems().then((resp) => setItem(resp));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => getItems(item)}>get item</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And replaced `return {items: response.Items, lastItem: response.LastEvaluatedKey};` with `return response.LastEvaluatedKey;`.

I thought that this would finally work. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ValidationException: The provided starting key is invalid: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

Comment: You don't appear to be storing `lastItemId` anywhere. You have to pass the `lastItemId` from the previous response to the function every time the button click happens. You aren't doing that, so the code has no idea that you want the next page.

Comment: @MarkB I tried numerous combinations of `lastItemId` - `getItems({ S: "3" })`, `getItems("3")`, `getItems({ postId: "3" })` - without luck. Am I missing a particular syntax?

Comment: You can't just make up values for that parameter. The value you need to pass is the same value you are sending in the response here: `lastItem: response.LastEvaluatedKey`. Whatever that value is in the response, needs to be passed as the parameter to get the next page.

Comment: @MarkB I followed your suggestion and updated my question. I'm getting an error even when passing the object.

Comment: You're passing the entire response back, instead of passing `resp.lastItem`.